# Is there a term for the language in which a language is taught?

Tags: terminology

If someone is a native speaker of Khmer, is living in New Zealand and is learning Russian from a tutor speaking English, I'd know how to refer to Khmer (the "native language"), and how to refer to Russian (the [target language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_language)). But what term would I use to refer to English in this scenario?

Should I use the term [medium of instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_of_instruction), or is that term more applicable to large-scale schools rather than one-on-one and class-based language learning?

Comment: Matrix language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no commonly accepted term for that.

Many schools use the following construct:

> **L2** for **L1** speakers

For example (mind the URLs and titles as well):

- [*Everyday Chinese for German Speakers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WOYDJS)
- [*English for Russian Speakers*](http://www.pimsleur.com/learn-english-for-russian-speakers)

So, in your case it would be *Russian for English speakers*, regardless the fact that the student's L1 is Khmer.

Answer (score 5):

I take it that *medium of instruction* includes the **language of instruction**. And that language of instructions is the language in which the target language is being taught.

(Unfortunately, I don't have a source for this but that's my sense from the literature I've read while researching and writing about language teaching)